# best way to generate unique id in java?

Tags: java

i want to make java class that generate the unique id for these field when user make his id it will always  be unqiue so how to do it in java?

```
String dairyId;
String userId;
String productId;
String MerchantId;
String couponId;
String eventId;
```

Comment: There is no best way.  It depends on your uniqueness requirements.  State them clearly and maybe we can answer

Comment: I would like to suggest Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+As you like.  :D

Answer (score 4):

UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID(); will give unique IDs,

Moreover according to [wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

> only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100
>   years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about
>   50%.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

```
UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
```

> The intent of UUIDs is to enable distributed systems to uniquely
>   identify information without significant central coordination. In this
>   context the word unique should be taken to mean "practically unique"
>   rather than "guaranteed unique". Since the identifiers have a finite
>   size, it is possible for two differing items to share the same
>   identifier.

So uniqueness across different runs is not guaranteed, but "practically guaranteed".

Comment: i am making if user register with my application then randomly make a id for him

Answer (score 1):

Of course UUID is the best solution but since Java 8 in private apps i always use:

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LocalDateTime localDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-SSS");
    String uid = localDateAndTime.format(formatter);
```

This saves having a separate datetime variable, is thread save and due to the `sleep(100)` it guarantees uniqueness in `SSS` milliseconds part and still is a 'human readable' UUID.

Comment: If two different running programs execute the code at the same time, they will both have the same uid. `Thread.sleep (100)` does not help in uniqueness extraction but only delays both programs in equal time.